# Alternative Proof for "Roots of Mertens Function-Farey Sequence-Cosines Relations"

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, alternative-proof, farey-sequences

You can write [Merten's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function#As_a_sum_over_Farey_sequences) as
$$
M(n)= \sum_{a\in \mathcal{F}_n} e^{2\pi i a}   ,
$$
where   $\mathcal{F}_n$   is the [Farey sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) of order $n$. The sum may be split into imaginary and real parts, due to $e^{2\pi i a}=\cos(2\pi a)+i\sin(2\pi a)$. Now when you plug in a root of $M(n)$ (I listed some [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/213259/19341)), you can easily see that the imaginary part is zero since the Farey sequence is symmetric around $\frac12$.

Further when you take $n$ to the limit of infinitely large roots of $M(n)$, the single addends approach the cosine function,

$\hskip1.8in$[image]

which again makes it easy to determine the value of the sum resp. integral, but

> is it possible to prove by other means than Farey and Mertens, like for example trigonometric identities, that the real part is zero?

For the non-believers, here the simplest non-trivial example:

$$\scriptstyle{
\cos{6/23 \pi}+\cos{2/39 \pi}+\cos{14/39 \pi}-\cos{19/39 \pi}-\cos{5/39 \pi}-\cos{17/39 \pi}+\cos{2/21 \pi}+\cos{2/37 \pi}-\cos{13/37 \pi}-\cos{11/27 \pi}\\
+\cos{6/29 \pi}-\cos{17/37 \pi}+\cos{16/33 \pi}+\cos{10/27 \pi}+\cos{4/29 \pi}+\cos{4/25 \pi}-\cos{9/31 \pi}-\cos{11/37 \pi}-\cos{15/37 \pi}-\cos{7/33 \pi}\\-\cos{13/33 \pi}+\cos{8/39 \pi}+\cos{2/33 \pi}+\cos{8/37 \pi}-\cos{3/35 \pi}-\cos{9/23 \pi}+\cos{14/37 \pi}+\cos{8/23 \pi}+\cos{8/33 \pi}+\cos{2/35 \pi}\\-\cos{1/21 \pi}+\cos{8/21 \pi}+\cos{4/23 \pi}+\cos{14/33 \pi}-\cos{1/37 \pi}+\cos{4/31 \pi}-\cos{7/27 \pi}+\cos{4/37 \pi}-\cos{9/25 \pi}+\cos{8/25 \pi}\\-\cos{3/31 \pi}+\cos{10/31 \pi}+\cos{4/35 \pi}-\cos{7/23 \pi}+\cos{12/37 \pi}-\cos{13/35 \pi}+\cos{12/25 \pi}+\cos{12/35 \pi}+\cos{10/21 \pi}-\cos{9/37 \pi}+\cos{16/39 \pi}+\cos{10/37 \pi}-\cos{7/29 \pi}+\cos{2/29 \pi}-\cos{13/29 \pi}-\cos{11/23 \pi}-\cos{11/35 \pi}+\cos{10/33 \pi}-\cos{3/25 \pi}+\cos{10/23 \pi}+\cos{2/25 \pi}-\cos{5/27 \pi}+\cos{8/29 \pi}-\cos{3/29 \pi}+\cos{6/37 \pi}+\cos{6/31 \pi}+\cos{16/35 \pi}-\cos{3/37 \pi}-\cos{5/23 \pi}-\cos{7/31 \pi}\\-\cos{11/39 \pi}+\cos{2/23 \pi}-\cos{5/33 \pi}+\cos{8/27 \pi}-\cos{13/31 \pi}-\cos{1/27 \pi}+\cos{10/29 \pi}-\cos{1/35 \pi}-\cos{5/21 \pi}+\cos{10/39 \pi}\\-\cos{5/29 \pi}-\cos{1/33 \pi}+\cos{18/37 \pi}+\cos{12/29 \pi}+\cos{4/27 \pi}-\cos{1/31 \pi}+\cos{4/33 \pi}-\cos{7/25 \pi}+\cos{2/27 \pi}+\cos{2/31 \pi}\\+\cos{6/25 \pi}+\cos{14/29 \pi}-\cos{5/37 \pi}+\cos{14/31 \pi}-\cos{17/35 \pi}-\cos{1/29 \pi}+\cos{8/35 \pi}-\cos{13/27 \pi}-\cos{15/31 \pi}-\cos{1/23 \pi}\\+\cos{6/35 \pi}+\cos{4/39 \pi}-\cos{11/31 \pi}-\cos{11/29 \pi}+\cos{16/37 \pi}-\cos{11/25 \pi}-\cos{7/39 \pi}+\cos{12/31 \pi}+\cos{8/31 \pi}-\cos{9/29 \pi}\\+\cos{4/21 \pi}-\cos{7/37 \pi}-\cos{1/25 \pi}-\cos{5/31 \pi}-\cos{1/39 \pi}-\cos{9/35 \pi}-\cos{3/23 \pi} \overset{!}{=}0}
$$