# Sums of the negative integer powers of $\zeta$ zeros have an analytical expression...?

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

The Mathworks page on [Riemann's $\zeta$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeros.html) says:

> Let $\rho_k$ denote the $k$th nontrivial zero of $\zeta(s)$, and write the sums of the negative integer powers of such zeros as
>   $$
> Z(n)=\sum_k\rho_k^{-n} 
> $$
>   ...
>   Such sums can be computed analytically, and the first few are
>   $$
> Z(1) = \frac12[2+\gamma-\ln(4\pi)] =0.0230957... 
> $$
>   where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant,...

How to prove that? It can be simplified (assuming RH) to
$$
Z(1) = \sum_k \frac4{(1+4t_k^2)}
$$
where $t_k$ is the imaginary part of $\rho_k$, *but they are thought likely to be transcendental numbers* ([from here and references therein](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/271819/19341)).

Comment: $\gamma$ is thought to be transcendental, and having a 'closed form' does not change the fact that it is. (Just because something has a closed form, that does not make it algebraic or even rational). For example, $\ln 2$ is transcendental, but it does not look complex and has a simple closed form. Hence, having a closed form and being transcendental are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams thanks for pointing that out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from
$$
\xi(s)=s(s-1)\pi^{s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{2}\exp(b s)\prod_\rho\left(1-\frac{s}{\rho}\right)\exp(s/\rho)
$$
with $b=\log(2\pi)-1-\gamma/2$.
Take the logarithmic derivative and group $\rho$ with $1-\rho$ to get
$$
\frac{\xi^\prime}{\xi}(s)=b+\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{\rho-s}.
$$
So $\xi^\prime/\xi(0)$ allows you to compute $Z(1)$.  Higher derivatives give $Z(n)$ in general.

Comment: Thanks, but one question if you don't mind: What does your Gravatar represent?

Comment: It's a plot of $\arg(\zeta(s))$, where the interval $[0,2\pi]$ is mapped to the color wheel.  See my webpage.