# Is it an open problem about Riemann Hypothesis non-trivial zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis

Let's assume RH was correct, and $1/2+Ki$ is any one of non-trivial zero of $\zeta$, is following problem open?

1) $K$ is irrational number

2) $K$ is transcendental number

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/121786/137524

Comment: Got it.. thanks Semiclassical!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problems are still open as currently no one knows what $K$ is: either irrational number or transcendental number.