# Are imaginary parts of roots of $\zeta$ always non-integers?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

We don't know if the imaginary parts of the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function are irrational ([Rational Roots of Riemann's $\zeta$ Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121786/rational-roots-of-riemanns-zeta-function)).

But do we know if the imaginary parts are always *non-integers*?